# Update existing mongodb data into an embedded document

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB so this is probably a basic question (hopefully). I currently have 10 million records with 410 fields loaded in a mongodb collection like so:

```
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("........"),
      "AddressID" : 123455,
      "IndividualId" : 1,
      "personfirstname" : "FirstName",
      "personmiddleinitial" : "M",
      "personlastname" : "LastName",
      "etc": "....."

    }
```

I need to wrap all of this data into an embedded document like so:

```
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("........"),
      "data" : {
            "AddressID" : 123455,
            "IndividualId" : 1,
            "personfirstname" : "FirstName",
            "personmiddleinitial" : "M",
            "personlastname" : "LastName",
            "etc": "....."
    }
```

I don't necessarily need to update this data in-place but that would be nice. If I need to export this data somehow specifying the new format and then re-import the new, updated data that is fine. Performing this via the MongoDB shell would be ideal.

Comment: Have you checked out Aggregation - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/ (which creates new documents in stages). One possibility might be to start with the $project stage, create a new field (`data`) and then include the others from your document in there - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project

Comment: Like what @DaveCoast said, you need to run an aggregate pipeline `db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": { 
            "data": "$$ROOT"
        }
    }, 
    { "$out": "collection" }
])`. Take note that this does not update your collection but creates a new one void of any existing indexes or replaces the existing collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by chridam within comments you can execute the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    { $project: { _id: "$_id", data: "$$ROOT" } },
    { $out: "newCollectionName" }
]);
```

This way you have the `_id` field both at root level and in the `data` object. Thus, you can execute a massive update to unset the second one:

```
db.newCollectionName.updateMany(
    {},
    { $unset: { "data._id": "" } }
);
```

Finally, you can drop the first collection and rename the second to restore the original name on the updated collection:

```
db.collectionName.drop();
db.newCollectionName.rename("collectionName");
```

This approach fully works within the database, avoiding fetching any of your 10 million documents.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the question of "Update existing mongodb data into an embedded document" This is creating a whole new collection.

Comment: Your update will only update the first matched document, you need to give a `multi: true` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in the shell with the following

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc = { _id: doc._id, data: doc };
    delete doc.data._id;
    db.test.save(doc);
    });
```

For example, if we insert the following documents:

```
> db.test.insertMany([
... {
...    _id: ObjectId("5a91af8908e17c5997e03b7e"),
...    field1: false,
...    field2: 0,
...    field3: "No"
... },
... {
...    _id: ObjectId("5a91afbc08e17c5997e03b7f"),
...    field1: true,
...    field2: 1,
...    field3: "Yes"
... }])
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedIds" : [
                ObjectId("5a91af8908e17c5997e03b7e"),
                ObjectId("5a91afbc08e17c5997e03b7f")
        ]
}
```

Then run:

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc = { _id: doc._id, data: doc };
    delete doc.data._id;
    db.test.save(doc);
    });
```

Our documents now look like this:

```
> db.test.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a91af8908e17c5997e03b7e"),
        "data" : {
                "field1" : false,
                "field2" : 0,
                "field3" : "No"
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a91afbc08e17c5997e03b7f"),
        "data" : {
                "field1" : true,
                "field2" : 1,
                "field3" : "Yes"
        }
}
```